# Can't parse int related to - "Cannot implicitly convert type string to int"

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I know this question has been covered extensively, but I am caught up on it regardless.  I can't figure out why my parse is not working.  I have a textbox control on a form that I am accessing from another class but I keep getting the above mentioned error and don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Edit : XtraForm
{
    public int _PatientID;
    public string _FirstName;
    public string _LastName;
    public string _Address;
    public string _City;
    public string _State;
    public string _ZipCode;
    public string _Phone;

    public Edit(int _PatientID, string _FirstName, string _LastName,
                string _Address, string _City, string _State,
                string _ZipCode, string _Phone)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // This is the line I am talking about
        _PatientID = Convert.ToInt32(txtPatientID.Text);

        _FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
        _LastName = txtLastName.Text;
        _Address = txtAddress.Text;
        _City = txtCity.Text;
        _State = txtState.Text;
        _ZipCode = txtZipCode.Text;
        _Phone = txtPhone.Text;
    }

    public class PatientService 
    {
        Edit ed = new Edit(_PatientID, _FirstName, _LastName, _Address,
                           _City, _State, _ZipCode, _Phone);

        SACommand cmd = new SACommand
             (@"INSERT INTO patient(patient_id, first_name, last_name,
                                    address, city, state, zipcode, phone) 
             VALUES ('" 
             + _PatientID + "','" 
             + _FirstName + "','"
             + _LastName + "','"
             + _Address + "','"
             + _City + "','"
             + _State + "','"
             + _ZipCode + "','"
             + _Phone + "');");
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("A new patient has been inserted");
        conn.Close();
     }
```

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: I suspect you're getting the error because the text in the text box can't be converted to a number. What is the value in that text box?

Comment: Also it is not a good practice to insert values directly into your sql statement, this leaves you open for SQL Injection attacks. You should use Parameters

Comment: In your constructor you are change local parameters and not class fields anyway..

Comment: show your error exception

Comment: Note that you are doing something not so good here. You are defining int _PatientID as public and as a parameter to a sub. This is confusing. Also, this code should not be part of VS initializecomponent.

Comment: Anytime you get an exception (with full stack trace) the line number is the most important piece of information in it.  Please look at that, and if you still don't understand what's going on, point out which line it is in the question.  (but don't make us count and guess pls)

Comment: I can't see how `Convert` could generate that error as you as not making any implicit casts. Are you certain it's this specific line that is causing you this error?

Comment: You are inserting PatientID as a quoted value. Does your DB allow quoted integers?

Comment: @codemonkeh heh duh, the "int" is totally a string by the time the DB would see it.  nice catch.  I was gonna blame zip-code, but just wasn't looking close enough...

Comment: To elaborate on what @EmmadKareem said, your constructor is all wrong. It takes in a lot of value parameters that "hide" the class members with the same name. Then you assign to the constructor parameters, *not* to the class members (fields, should maybe have been properties), so that is bad. And are you sure you want to read values from text boxes (?) in the constructor?

Comment: Hey guys, I really appreciate all the help.  I'm a little overwhelmed where to start right now with all the different input.  I am going to try the parametized input this time and see how it goes.  I will report back once finished.

Comment: @Jeppe, I will look at the constructor and reevaluate.  Thanks.

Comment: Pretty much any invalid input I can think up will give you an `Input string is not in correct format` error... I don't think the `Convert.ToInt32` is raising this error.

Comment: @Steve, yes I am just now realizing that I have way more issues in my code than just that line.  Thanks.

Comment: So a good start would be to change all the public fields to private properties?

Comment: Or maybe not because then I can't access the controls in my other class?

Comment: Use properties. Have a look at the link in my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

As comments said, don't use direct sql, try paramaters, will give you extra safety (Here's a little page that will give you a head start: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter).

Another one: use C# properties, not public fields. Here's [C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x9fsa0sw.aspx) page about them.

If you want to parse a string to int, Convert.ToInt32(string) should work, but it might throw an exception. Have a look at this from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Using the ToInt32(String) method is equivalent to passing value to the Int32.Parse(String) method. value is interpreted by using the formatting conventions of the current thread culture.
>   If you prefer not to handle an exception if the conversion fails, you can call the Int32.TryParse method instead. It returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed.

So you can try a `TryParse` if you want to mitigate an exception (and maybe use a default value).

As far as your code goes, it SHOULD work ... can you put a break point in there and see what the value of `txtPatientID.Text` is?